# Skip client side validation in Trinidad without immediate="true"

Tags: validation, jsf, client, skip, trinidad

I am using MyFaces Trinidad JSF 2 and want to skip the client side validations but still update the bean on a button click and navigate to a different page.

I do not want to use `immediate="true"` as I want the bean to be updated. I am not sure how to use `<f:ajax>`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention immediate="true" but if you want to have values in your then do the following, in execute attribute mention all the input components for which you want to see values in bean.

immediate=true execute="id1, id2, ...."

this way, validation will be skipped but some input component's values also submitted to the server which are set into the bean.

I hope you understand....